# Why is my android studio kotlin plugin version in different format than my co-workers?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I stumbled into an issue where all my unit test classes fail to run, providing the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name <my class name>. Reason: toPrettyPrint (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; in <my class name>: inconsistent stack height -1
```

One user commented on the following github thread for powermock, that the same error first happened to them after updating their kotlin plugin:
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/779
After reading this, I have checked with my colleagues to see maybe they have a different kotlin version, and saw that their kotlin plugin version is
**203.1.6.0-release-798-AS7717.8**, whereas mine is **1.4.32-release-Studio4.1-1**.
What I find peculiar abbout this, is that these versions dont follow the same conventions, they look more like two completely different sofware. Is there any way for me to get the same version for my kotlin plugin ?
Any help or clarification is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They probably just changed the naming scheme for the plugin. Looks like you have one that is about one and a half years out of date.

Anyway, go to File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin and click the Install button.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed it was an old plugin, after updating android studio, it presented the option for installing the most recent kotlin version in the settings page you mentioned. Thanks!